# ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() against specific process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Trying to play with different processes to read data from the memory. And for some reason it works for almost all processes on my pc but fails with only one specific (so far). I can't understand why its happening and if there some kind of security stuff applied or what? Any help will be appreciated.

The process that I'm trying hook is x64 but I've tested this code with different x64 processes and it worked without issue. So I don't think its compile/x32/x64 problem. I will be happy if some one can tell when to go from there.

So I can get the correct Process Id but fail to read modules from:

```cpp
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName) {

    uintptr_t modBaseAdr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);

    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED == errorCode) {
            std::cout << "Got Error Access Denied code: " << errorCode << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Unhandled error code: " << errorCode << std::endl;
        }

    }
    else {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);

        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
            do {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
                    modBaseAdr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseSize;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAdr;
}
```

Output:

```sh
procId = 0x4398
Got Error Access Denied code: 5
```

UPD:

- 0x4398 process (actually a game) which is running from my user. its not the system or protected process.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the process ID in Task Manager to see which process it is? Maybe it is a protected system process. Or, there are other ways to deny access. Maybe restrictive security permissions are on the process/file. Maybe the process uses drivers that block `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: I think the reason is that this process is running under a different account with higher privileges, and that all your other process are running under your account

Comment: @RemyLebeau  thank you for so fast response! its process that I'm running from my user name. Its actual a game so not the system process. I will try to look and understand what is sec perm and driver block but if you have a link to good article that explain that I will be happy to learn from it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer answered above ^

Comment: Maybe it is a protected process light. (Not a full protected process.)

Comment: @kyxap there are several questions on StackOverflow related to access denied errors on `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I know I've looked on all of them no solution or details on how to approach the problem

Comment: *"how to approach the problem"* - It hasn't become obvious what that problem is. That said, games are special. Generally speaking, every game has rules. Rules are an integral part, and game software will invest significant effort into establishing those rules. The only reason to peek inside the memory reflecting the game state is to evade the game's rules. This is commonly referred to as cheating. So, anyway... what *problem* are you trying to solve?